# How to forward to another page in a managed bean constructor?

Tags: java, jsf, forwarding

How can I forward to another page inside the constructor of a backing bean? I don't want to use redirect.

EDIT:

Thank you very much [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379114/839601).

Is `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("page.jsf")` safe if I call it inside a getter method? The getter method will be invoked by JSF in the Render Response phase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke a method to do this.  Constructors are not methods, and cannot return the "PAGE2" string.